# If cellA does not contain contents of cellB, set cellC to cellD

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

any idea what's wrong with my formula - I want to set the content of C5 to the content of B4, if the content of A5 cannot be found in A4...

Current formula is:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH<>(A5,A4)),B4,"")
```

Excel screenshot:

[image]

Comment: SEARCH<> is not correct. If you want to use the search function then it would be SEARCH(...args...), that is how all Excel functions work.

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A5,A4)), B4, "")`

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that Find() i case sensitive I think you can try:

```
=IF(IFERROR(IF(FIND(A5,A4)>0,1),0),C5,"")
```